# How does ArrayList.get return its objects?

Tags: java

**Context:** I'm making a mini-interpreter-ish calculator thing. I figured that the best way to hold the symbol table was to make an ArrayList of an Object that I've defined (name of the object is WiP). Setting up the ArrayList looks like.

```
ArrayList<miniVariable> vList = new ArrayList<miniVariable>();
```

Simple enough, and the `miniVariable` Object contains the following variables

```
    public String name;
    public double value; 
    public boolean initialized;
```

They are public because I already made setter/getters in the class with the ArrayList, when I didn't realize you could make one of Objects, and I don't want to move everything over. I probably should.

**Question:** If I were to call `vList.get(index) .value = 5;` would it actually change the value being stored in the `vList(index)`'s `value` variable? Or does `.get(index)`just return a copy  of the data, and so changing this copy doesn't actually do anything?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?  Quicker than posting this question I think

Comment: It returns the object itself

Comment: I believe adding to an ArrayList does allow for direct modification through there since it stores the memory location of the same object

Comment: Java always uses pass (return) by value ... where in the value is a reference for reference classes (objects / arrays).

Comment: The answer is that you would change the value of `value` for the object in the list.

Comment: Thank you  for your answers. And actually, short-cutting the code which is currently unimplemented takes a lot longer than typing up what question I have. And on the plus side, if it's a conceptual question, I can tend to work it out by trying to explain it as a question, and not ever have to actually submit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It changes the value on the original instance, as one would expect.

Creating a copy of an object in Java only happens explicitly (and usually with some difficulty at that).

A few other notes:

- Class names in should be `CapitalCase`.
- Implementing getters and setters on an object holding a list of objects is bad practice as it violates [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). If you're implementing getters and setters, it's best to put them on the class they apply to.

Answer (score 0):

What you are storing in the `ArrayList` is not the object itself, but *reference* to object.

So when you do `vList.get(i)` it is returning you the reference that you previous put in.  Which means you are going to access the same object that you previous put in the list, instead of a copy of it.

Get yourself familiar with one of the basic concept of Java, which is Reference and Primitive types.

Some off-topic suggestions:

- Make sure you are aware of Java's naming convention. For example, for the class name, it should be `MiniVariable` instead of `miniVariable`.
- Just to be more accurate: *"and the miniVariable Object contains the following variable"*, `MiniVariable` is a class, but not an object.  You may say "and a MiniVariable object (instance) contains these member fields", or "in MiniVariable class defined the following member fields"

Answer (score 0):

All collections objects stores reference to object , if you change any thing on  object directly(accessing through collection) or indirectly ( already have reference of it) it will change the state of the object stored in collection